# AngularJs- Calling a directive from $scope function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have my angular JS directive as below

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr)
    {
        $(elem).click(function () {                
             //do some stuff     
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

I know I can invoke this by this way

```
   <a href ng-click="somefunction()" myDirective>« First</a>
```

I need to invoke this from a function defined in my scope, which is in the same controller

```
$scope.FunctionToCallDirective =  function()
{
//need to all directive from here
}
```

How do I modify my directive ?

Comment: Is your `$scope` part of another directive? Or is it part of a controller?

Comment: It is the same directive

Comment: Invoke the click binding or the stuff that the click does?

Comment: stuff that click does @iceless